# Arduino: error: expected unqualified-id before 'if' (using ping sensor)

Tags: if-statement, arduino, ping

I am having issues with a script I modified.  I'm getting an "
Ping_Library_Example:9: error: expected unqualified-id before 'if'"
I'm sure I have some little syntax error somewhere, any ideas what?
The orrigional script, by the way, has "void loop" instead of "if".  This same probably also occurs when using when, with the same error.  Any ideas?

```
#include <Ping.h>

Ping ping = Ping(13,74,29);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

if(digitalRead == HIGH){
  ping.fire();
  Serial.print("Microseconds: ");
  Serial.print(ping.microseconds());
  Serial.print(" | Inches ");
  Serial.print(ping.inches());
  Serial.print(" | Centimeters: ");
  Serial.print(ping.centimeters());
  Serial.println();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arduino programs need a `loop()` function to run; simply replacing the function with an `if` condition doesn't work. Try putting the `if` block inside a `loop()` function.

Additionally, `digitalRead` is a function, and you need to tell it what pin to read from. e.g., `digitalRead(5)` to read from pin 5.

Try something like this:

```
void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(5) == HIGH) {
    ping.fire();
    // insert other code here
  }
}
```

(change 5 to whatever pin you want to read from, or assign that value to a variable and pass that in)

Answer (score 3):

You can't write if expression outside function. I think it should be like this:

```
void loop() {
   if(digitalRead(5) == HIGH){ //checks pin 5
     ping.fire();
     Serial.print("Microseconds: ");
     Serial.print(ping.microseconds());
     Serial.print(" | Inches ");
     Serial.print(ping.inches());
     Serial.print(" | Centimeters: ");
     Serial.print(ping.centimeters());
     Serial.println();
   }
}
```

This code loops, checks if digitalRead is HIGH and if yes, makes ping.
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

For some additional information that may be helpful to someone who stumbled on this answer,

I just had the same problem but my issue was that there was one } accidentally omitted from the end. This caused the if statement to be outside of any function. Simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

I received same error due to a backslash typo in a comment, if you can imagine such a thing. The offending lines were:

```
int my_recvDone() {
    //=======================\
    if ( !g_patternReceived ) {
```

I assume this is due to some kind of line continuance feature in the parser, and probably would manifest as a different compiler error in other areas of code...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Visual Micro instead of the Arduino IDE, I was getting this error too.  In Visual Micro there is a breakpoint that automatically gets set to the beginning of the loop() function.  For whatever reason, the breakpoint was set on the line before the loop function.  Resetting that breakpoint to the same line as the loop function resolved this error.